# Algorithm to reduce and limit memory usage of a set combination search

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations, scalability, set-theory

I would like to reduce and limit the memory footprint used in comparing all combinations of items in a set to each other, where the set could grow to any size. I was thinking of splitting up the set into smaller pieces but then as all combinations are required, I can't see how to do that without ending up needing all combinations in memory at some point.

e.g. if I have items A,B,C,D,E,F I need to compare all different combinations

```
  A B C D E F
A  
B x
C x x
D x x x
E x x x x
F x x x x x
```

and so on. The sets are typically of 100's to 10,000's of documents with metadata to be checked with various heuristics.

I currently am achieving it (without loading all items into memory at once), by iterating over the set twice in two identical nested database queries using a cursor in each to iterate across the two dimensions of the combinations. This is theoretically unlimited in scale and uses very little memory, but feels a bit wasteful as I will be querying for each item N+1 times (where N is the size of the set). It stresses the database a bit of course.

This is the current simple algorithm:

- Prepare query for set
- while cursor.next A:

  - Prepare query for set, excluding A
  - while cursor.next B:

    - Compare A with B

This results in the sequence AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, BA, BC, BD etc. and I only ever keep two documents in memory at once, but it has two problems. Firstly the inner query happens N times. If I wasn't excluding A in the query, it would be the very same query re-run N times, which just seems wasteful. The second problem is this is permutations, so I'm doing twice as much work as needed and having to dedupe the results.

I thought about caching the items as I progress, but realised it would simply grow to eventually contain all items anyway to complete all combinations. So this lead full circle to the basic idea of just selecting the entire set once into memory and scanning the combinations from one array. This is simple but of course not scalable.

**So, is there an algorithm to perform a comparison of all combinations of distinct pairs in a set, by only using partitions of the set at any one time, which is guaranteed to sum up to covering all combinations?**

I couldn't think of one naively. e.g. if you split it in two halves, you still need to load the combination of the two sub-sets at some point. Perhaps "all odds" and "all evens" but that would only halve the scalability issue.

```
  B D F
B 
D x  
F x x
```

then

```
  A C E
A  
C x  
E x x
```

but this misses half the combos.

I've got a feeling its theoretically impossible, but wondering if there might be a clever mathematical trick out there. Or I'm missing something really obvious.

UPDATE 
- question edited and hopefully clarified after initial comments.

Nikos.M has given me the idea of pre-generating the combination pair's "indexes" then I could query for each pair.

I was originally hoping to achieve what MicSim calls the "sweet spot" of some middle ground of batch sizes. So not atomically loading every pair at one extreme, nor loading the entire set at the other end, but some fixed-size batching method to keep the processing footprint flat.

Comment: there is a way to generate all combinations or subsets of n objects one-by-one systematicaly and there is only one combination active in memory. if this solves the problem let me know tso I post the algorithm

Comment: But I would need some clarification on what you mean by combinations exactly? The examples you post are neither combinations (ie choose k from n) nor subsets( all subsets of n items), except if you miss something

Comment: For example [see here](https://foo123.github.io/examples/abacus) for efficient generation of various combinatorial objects and let me know which one you need so I can post associoated algorithm

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it's not combinations I need? This is the same as the example in my first table: https://foo123.github.io/examples/abacus/#action=produce&object=combination&type=default&order=&N=6&K=2&alphabet=&Text=

Comment: Ok so you need an algorithm for combinations of choosing 2 from N (where N may be 100.000 for example)? Do I understand correctly? Initialy i thought you needed actually subsets which are ALL combinations of chossing k from N for k=1 to N.

Comment: The way to say what you want is "all pairs of distinct items".  See those nice matrices you drew in your post?  Divide the lower triangle (with the xs) into small squares, and do each square separately.

Comment: To help the others: You want to optimize space while don't losing up on performance reading the documents. The comparison time doesn't matter in your case (because reading costs are way larger than comparing). **Option 1:** reading all documents at once and comparing would cost you O(N^2) space for the results and O(N) time for reading, **Option 2:** reading only 2 documents at a time would cost you O(1) space for the result, but O(N^2) time reading.  You are probably looking for some sweet spot in between with both of the 2 values being at most O(N log N).

Comment: I think you are trying to iterate over all unordered pairs of items, without loading all of the items into memory at once, and minimising the number of times that items are loaded. Is that a correct interpretation of your question?

Comment: @NikosM. yes I need the combinations. I was just putting subsets out there as a possible solution to the scalability problem, but open to ideas.

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes "all pairs of distinct items" is right, I've edited the answer. OK I think I see what you mean - small squares being the subsets, but how do I achieve that algorithmically? I guess I need one of Nikos's set generators...

Comment: @MicSim thanks yes, I'm not a mathematician so never got familiar with those notations (I know I should though!). Is it about trading space for time. I don't mind the user having to wait for an unlimited amount of time, but I cannot provide an unlimited amount of memory. In theory they could load a million documents, they'd just have to wait a long time, which might be fine.

Comment: @kaya3 yes that's very succinct. I wish I had written that one sentence instead of my rambling question!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE ==========================================**

If I understand correctly the question. There is **no method** to partition the set into **independent** sub-sets that are **non-overlapping**, in order to reduce memory usage, since by definition everything  must be compared with everything else. So there is no such cut that can partition the set. However by employing combinations one can minimize the impact, having **only 2 active documents** in memory at each instance, and update documents when next combination **actually references a different document** (**referencing 2 different documents from previous combination is actually rare, only one document reference changes on average from one combination to the next one**). Also by using below combinations approach, process **can stop at some point and save last combination on disk, and at some later time resume from that point on** the process. So it can be efficient, but a kind of `N+1 problem` still exists in some sense. For the combinations approach, see below original answer.

**==================================================**

There are algorithms to generate combinations one-by-one systematicaly, where you do NOT need to store ALL combinations in memory at once but have ONLY ONE active at each instant.

The algorithm works by having as input a combination and returning the next combination (eg in lexicographic order) untill the last one is reached.

The initial combination of choosing `2` from `n` (where `n >= 2` ) is `[0,1]`

**note** if `n < 2` there are no combinations that choose `2` elements from a set with less than `2` elements.

The successor algorithm is (in python):

```
def next_combination( item, n, k ):
    MIN = 0
    MAX = k-1
    j = n-k
    i = MAX
    index = -1
    # find index to move
    while(MIN<=i and i<=MAX):
        if item[i] < j+i:
            index = i
            break
        i -= 1
    # adjust next indexes after the moved index
    if MIN<=index and index<=MAX:
        curr = item[index]+1
        j = n-k+index
        if curr == j:
            item[index] = curr
        elif curr < j:
            i = index
            while(MIN<=i and i<=MAX):
                item[i] = curr
                curr += 1
                i += 1
    else:
        # last item
        item = None
    return item
```

you use like the following:

```
comb = [0, 1] # first combination
doc1 = None
doc2 = None
prevcomb = None
while (comb):
    # process combination
    # eg:
    # doc1 = docs.get(comb[0]) if (not prevcomb) or (prevcomb[0]!=comb[0]) else doc1
    # doc2 = docs.get(comb[1]) if (not prevcomb) or (prevcomb[1]!=comb[1]) else doc2
    # compare(doc1, doc2)
    # when finished, compute next combination untill last
    prevcomb = comb[:] # copy
    comb = next_combination(comb, n, 2) # get next combination in order
```

[Online test for k=2, n=6](https://repl.it/repls/TrustworthyCarefreeSource)

**note2** the time complexity of the above algorithm is efficient, in fact it is a CAT algorithm (ie takes **constant average time per combination**) to generate whole set of combinations.

**note3** there are even faster algorithms for special cases, eg where n is small. One such algorithm uses only smart bitwise operations on `32bit` or `64bit` unsigned integers (thus possible only for `n <= 64`)

**note4** The above algorithm (for python) can also be adjusted to use `iterator` pattern or `generator` pattern (ie `yield`), but as is can be implemented easily in any language even those which do not support generators

**note5** for `k=2` the combinations algorithm can also be implemented using a nested loop as well (since in this case they coincide)
ie:

```
def next_combination2(n):
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            yield [i, j]
```

**note6** if another language is used let me know to re-post algorithm in another language if possible (eg: php, javascript, c)

Comment: Thanks your update sounds like you have understood my question better (I've improved it for clarity too). I had not considered pre-generating the combinations themselves and so was not originally worried about the memory for the combination "indexes" ie. just the metadata, but I can see now that even that would be a problem. I tried using your site to generate 100,000 combinations and it froze my browser :)

Comment: I like the idea of using the combination generator - I had not thought of that (I was just doing it implicitly by looping over arrays or cursors). I have used generators in python. I am currently working in Node javascript, but I can translate. What I could do is run the generator for X cycles, where X is my batch size. Then query the DB for all items in the X combinations, then perform the comparisons. Then generate the next X combinations.

Comment: @scipilot yeap noticed the delay too, but the bottleneck in this case is not generating the actual combinations (with this algorithm) which is fast, but computing the total number of combinations using big integer factorials and binomials which is done before any actual generation takes place. although for k=2 the total number is easy to compute yet computing it from the defintioon of binomial coefficient using the factorial of 100000 can slow down the process

Comment: @scipilot, in fact the `biginteger.js` library that i use for big integer calculations errors out with `"too much recursion"` error. This is what you see when the browser freezes. It has nothing to do with the actual generation algorithm per se

Comment: @scipilot, fixed total number computations freezing on site and lib, you can [test for combinations of 100000](https://foo123.github.io/examples/abacus/#action=produce&object=combination&type=default&order=&N=100000&K=2&alphabet=&Text=)